# How to configure HAProxy to "proxy" two domain names to different ports in localhost

Tags: tomcat8, haproxy

I have one server containing FE app and BE for it. FE listens port 80 and BE is deployed to Tomcat listening default port 8080. HAProxy is used to listen port 443 / handle ssl. Proxying to FE / port 80 works fine, but not to BE / Tomcat listening port 8080. Here's the configuration I'm using:

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        maxconn 3072
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/ssl.key
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private
        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        #ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httpchk
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        option  forwardfor
        option  http-server-close
        option  http-keep-alive
        option  abortonclose
        option  redispatch
        retries 3
        maxconn 3072
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

listen stats
        bind 0.0.0.0:9000
        mode http

frontend http-in
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/bundle.pem
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
        redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

        # Define hosts
        acl host_fe hdr(host) -i fe.domain.com
        acl host_be hdr(host) -i be.domain.com

        ## figure out which one to use
        use_backend fecluster if host_fe
        use_backend becluster if host_be

backend fecluster
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        server node1 localhost:80 cookie A check

backend becluster
        mode http
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
        http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
        redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
        server node1 localhost:8080 maxconn 32 check inter 5000 
        cookie node1
```

Tomcat works fine using ip address directly, so that's not the case. So help is needed for the host_be / becluster.